# Как в начале и в конце каждой строки вставить текст?

Tags: php

Как в начале и в конце каждой строки вставить текст?
Текст:

```
$text='абв абв
абв абв

абв абв';
$arr=explode("\n", $text);
foreach ($arr as $key => $str) {
$i++;
$output.="<div id='str".$i."'>".$str."</div>\n";
}
```

Он выдает

```
<div id='str1'>абв абв</div>
<div id='str2'>абв абв</div>
<div id='str3'></div>
<div id='str4'>абв абв</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы получилось

```
<div id='str1'>абв абв</div>
<div id='str2'>абв абв</div>
<br>
<div id='str3'>абв абв</div>
```

Comment: Вопросы, конечно, поражают воображение :)

Comment: что то не так?

Comment: if ($str=="") {
        ... // br
    } else {
        ... // div
    }

Comment: я пробовал всеровно в див выдает

Comment: а там где //br вы вставили естественно

    $output.="<br/>\n";

Comment: А если 

    <script>
    $("div#str2").after("<br>");
    </script>

Comment: @berserker PHP mod_jquery ?

Comment: jQuery API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как альтернативка:

```
$text='Как в начале и в конце каждой строки вставить текст?
Помогите, люди добрые!

Сами мы не местные.
a\na\na\n\naa\na (проверка на замечание @Чад)\n\naa\na';

$lines = preg_split('/\\r\\n?|\\n/', $text);
$new_str = '';
foreach($lines as $line){
    if($line){
        $new_str .= '<div>'.$line.'</div>';
    } else {
        $new_str .= '<br />';
    }
}
echo $new_str;
```

[Посмотреть код в работе](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/f1y-xb8)

Comment: Спасибо за такой ресурс. И да, мой код побыстрее ;D

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strlen($str) < 2) {
    $output .= "<br />\n";
} else {
    $output.="<div id='str".$i."'>".$str."</div>\n";
}
```

**UPD**

```
$arr=explode("<br />", nl2br($text));
foreach ($arr as $key => $str) {

if($str == "
") {
    $output .= "<br />\n";
} else {
    $i++;
    $output.="<div id='str".$i."'>".$str."</div>\n";
}

}
echo $output;
```

Comment: А если $text = 'a\na\na\n\naa\na' ?